# FFmpeg: How to convert vertical video with blurred background sides

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I execute the below command for blur the video background but i get error.

```
String[] complexCommand = {"-i", "" + yourRealPath, "-lavfi", "[0:v]scale=ih*16/9:-1",
    "boxblur=luma_radius=min(640,356)/20", ":luma_power=1:chroma_radius=min(cw,ch)/20",
    ":chroma_power=1[bg]", ";[bg][0:v]", "overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2",
    "crop=h=iw*9/16", "-vb", "800K", filePath};
```

ERROR :

> Unable to find a suitable output format for'boxblur=luma_radius=min(640,356)/20'
>       boxblur=luma_radius=min(640,356)/20: Invalid argument

Comment: Everything from `[0:v]scale` till `crop=h=iw*9/16` should be one argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet is working well for me:

```
"-i", input,
"-strict", "-2",
"-filter_complex", "[0:v]scale=ih*16/9:-1,boxblur=luma_radius=min(h\\,w)/20:luma_power=1:chroma_radius=min(cw\\,ch)/20:chroma_power=1[bg];[bg][0:v]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2,crop=h=iw*9/16",
"-c:v", "libx264",
"-pix_fmt", "yuv420p",
 output
```

Comment: Thanks.Its working.  Can you please explain how its work. 
Because Sometime I get error. 

**Invalid too big or non positive size for width '356' or height '356'**

Comment: You have to explore the input source to resolve that, maybe there is a metadata error and FFMPEG can't recognize width/height.